# Showing a sibling button based on its child span class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 buttons with glyphicons that I would like to show or hide based upon which one of the 3 is clicked.

Below is a sample of the buttons and an example of the click code. I get into the `if hasClass pencil` properly, it's hiding the sibling that doesn't work:

```
<div class="row contact-row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
</div>

$(".contact-row").on("click", ":button", function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.children("span").hasClass("glyphicon-pencil")) {
        $t.siblings().children().hasClass('glyphicon-remove').parent().hide();
    };
  }; //end .contact-row 'click'
```

what I am trying to do with this line is hide the button that contains a span with class `glyphicon-remove'

```
$t.siblings().children().hasClass('glyphicon-remove').parent().hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) returns boolean value, not a jQuery object. Instead use [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method to filter out elements which children has the certain class with help of [direct child selector `>`](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)(to check only direct child).

```
$t.siblings().has('>.glyphicon-remove').hide();
```

```js
$(".contact-row").on("click", ":button", function() {
  var $t = $(this);
  if ($t.children("span").hasClass("glyphicon-pencil")) {
    $t.siblings().has('>.glyphicon-remove').hide();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row contact-row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true">pencil</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">remove</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true">ban circle</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, it's a single line, and is safe for other buttons on the page to have the class.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because `hasClass()` returns a boolean value, not a jQuery object, so you cannot chain further jQuery methods from it. To fix this you could supply the `.glyphicon-remove` selector to `children()` directly:

```js
$(".contact-row").on("click", ":button", function() {
  var $t = $(this);
  if ($t.children("span").hasClass("glyphicon-pencil")) {
    $t.siblings().children('.glyphicon-remove').parent().hide();
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row contact-row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true">pencil</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">remove</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" aria-hidden="true">ban circle</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Note however that given the logic in the question, you can simply reduce the JS code to this and achieve the same result:

```
$(".contact-row").on("click", "button:has(.glyphicon-pencil)", function() {
    $('button:has(.glyphicon-remove)').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply...

```
$(".glyphicon-remove").parents("button").hide();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/324879L0/1/